# trying to get element by prefix of its name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery 1.3.2.
This is my code:

```
var additionsPricesItems = debitPrice.find('table[name|=Addition_]');
```

debitPrice holds the following structure:

```
<DIV name="DebitPrice"><SELECT name=CustomerSelect><OPTION value=5264>5113575921</OPTION></SELECT><BR><A jQuery1304508596343="43">הסר מחיר חיוב</A>
<TABLE class=PriceBox name="TaskPrice" jQuery1304508596343="45">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=SubTitle colSpan=2>debit price: </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>price: </TD>
<TD><INPUT value=11 type=text name=PriceInput jQuery1304508596343="44"><SELECT class=Small><OPTION selected value="">$</OPTION></SELECT></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>by unit: </TD>
<TD><SELECT class=Big name=UnitTypeSelect><OPTION selected value="">none</OPTION><OPTION value=QUANTITY>quantity</OPTION><OPTION value=VOLUME>volume</OPTION><OPTION value=WEIGHT>weight</OPTION></SELECT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE class=PriceBox name="Addition_219" jQuery1304508596343="350">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class=SubTitle colSpan=2>addition price: </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>price: </TD>
<TD><INPUT value=12 type=text name=PriceInput jQuery1304508596343="349"><SELECT class=Small><OPTION selected value="">$</OPTION></SELECT></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>by unit: </TD>
<TD><SELECT class=Big name=UnitTypeSelect><OPTION value="">none</OPTION><OPTION selected value=QUANTITY>quantity</OPTION></SELECT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>
```

for some reason, `additionsPricesItems.length` equals to zero - jquery doesn;t find any match elements. But there is one element with name prefix of "Addition_"!

Comment: Did you try the starts-with selector? `.find('table[name^="Addition_"]')`.

Comment: @rudi_visser: What is the difference between ^= and |= ?

Comment: `^=` is starts with, `|=` is contains. It *shouldn't* make a difference, but you never know.

Comment: @rudi_visser: You right, it worked. Write an answer and I wil give you your points.

Comment: see [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this:

```
debitPrice.find('table[name^="Addition_"]');
```

The `^=` is the *starts with* selector, whereas `|=` is the *contains prefix* selector.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
var additionsPricesItems = debitPrice.find('table[name^="Addition_"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify things, the `|=` selector means:

> Selects elements that have the
>   specified attribute with a value
>   either equal to a given string or
>   starting with that string followed by
>   a hyphen (-)

So if your name would have been `Addition_-219` that selector would have worked.

What you really need as others stated already is the `^=` selector that:

> Selects elements that have the
>   specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string

Information taken from the jQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var additionsPricesItems = debitPrice.find('table[name^="Addition_"]');
alert(additionsPricesItems.length
```